# What is the problem with my "pod install" command?

Tags: firebase, installation, cocoapods

I am trying to use Firebase to create a backend for my test application.

I was instructed to add // pod 'Firebase/Core' // to my podfile and then run // pod install // inside my terminal.

Here is what the terminal displayed...

......

```
Evans-MacBook-Pro:Version 1 evan$ pod install

Analyzing dependencies

Setting up CocoaPods master repo

  $ /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git --
progress --
  master
  Cloning into 'master'...

  remote: Enumerating objects: 174, done.        

  remote: Counting objects: 100% (174/174), done.   

  remote: Compressing objects: 100% (161/161), done.   

  error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining

  fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

  fatal: early EOF

  fatal: index-pack failed

[!] Unable to add a source with url `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` named `master`.
You can try adding it manually in `/Users/evan/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.

[!] Automatically assigning platform `ios` with version `12.1` on target `Version 1` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
```

......

I have a slow internet connection, I think... I am using my iPhone hotspot in a very rural area of Iowa.

After I press install in the terminal, the terminal seems to attempt to download 3 million objects at a rate of about 500 per second. This would take 100 minutes to complete... and consistently, after downloading about 5% of the objects, the errors above are returned.

Does anyone know how I can get past this? I am using Xcode 10.

I have tried doing the following:

```
cd to ~/.cocoapods/repos
```

then run:

```
 git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master
```

.....

Here is a picture of the terminal during the process:
[Terminal Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziNgF.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're in the folder containing the app workspace. (Ex: 'cd Desktop', 'Ls', 'cd myApp')

- Run 'sudo gem install cocoapods' to get the latest version of cocoapods
- Try firebase login to connect the app if you're using functions
- 'pod init' will create the podfile
- 'pod install' will generate a .xcworkspace file.